# jQuery - Set height of parent element to that of absolute positioned overlay, but only for service with active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to work out how to create a function that gets the height of the current opened class "overlay" once it has been "opened", and then apply that to the parent div of class "service-content".

I have pretty much managed that, but I'm not sure how to contain it to the service that has the overlay opened. At the moment it gives the first element clicked height to all available classes.

I got this far:

https://codepen.io/gooseygander/pen/vWMQgd

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //Click element to show content overlay
  $('.open-overlay').click(function() {
    //traverse dom to get the parent container
    //Finder service overlay container and add/toggle the open lass
    jQuery(this).closest('.service-contentContainer').find('.overlay').addClass('overlay--open');
  });
  $('.close-overlay').click(function() {
    //traverse dom to get the parent container
    //Finder service overlay container and add/toggle the open lass
    $(this).closest('.service-contentContainer').find('.overlay').removeClass('overlay--open');
  });

  $(".open-overlay").click(function() {
    if ($('.serviceOverlay--open')) {
      function setTheHeight() {
        var maxHeight = $(".service-content").outerHeight();
        $('.service-content').height(maxHeight);
      };
      setTheHeight();
      $(window).resize(function() {
        setTheHeight();
      });
    };
  });

  if (!$('#mydiv').hasClass("serviceOverlay--open")) {
    $('.service').removeAttr('height');
  }

});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.service {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 20%;
}

.service-contentContainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.service-content {
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
}

.overlay--open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="service">
  <div class="service-contentContainer">
    <div class="service-content">
      <h1>Header </h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
        </p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open-overlay">Open overlay</a>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-overlay">Close overlay</a>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="service">
  <div class="service-contentContainer">
    <div class="service-content">
      <button class="open-overlay">Open overlay</button>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-overlay">Close overlay</a>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="service">
  <div class="service-contentContainer">
    <div class="service-content">
      <button class="open-overlay">Open overlay</button>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-overlay">Close overlay</a>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, itaque nihil. Tenetur assumenda exercitationem quibusdam suscipit adipisci eveniet? Placeat nemo laudantium aperiam possimus officia neque iste voluptate atque rem consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction to contain this function to the individual service content that the overlay has been activated, and maybe how to remove it once closed?

Cheers

Comment: Close to [this](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/aVxPKR?editors=1011)?

Comment: Hey @LouysPatriceBessette. Not really. The height needs to be added to each service, dependant on whichever has been opened and then removed (set back to default when closed).

Comment: Okay... So you wil then do the opposite. You will open all your services on load, so the script will be able to "measure" each heights. Then, you close them all and set the default height (just for the open button) to all of them. On open, you set the height to what was measured and stored to an array.

Comment: Hey Louys, I will give this a crack and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Okay. Feel free to reply here if needed.